# Sql service broker and SqlDependency

Tags: sql-server, trigger, c#, service-broker, change-tracking

I have a system where my TCP/IP command prompt application receive data and insert that data in `[database1].[mytable]`.

Now I want to move that data from `[database1].[mytable]` to `[database2].[anothertable]` when any new record insert in `[database1].[mytable]` without losing any single data.

And there are a approx 70/100 records insert at every 1 second in `[database1].[mytable]`. Now I want to move that data and have to do some calculation and then insert into `[database2].[anothertable]`.

I have tried **triggered and Stored procedures** as well but it take too much database memory though sometime my db hangs when there are concurrent user try to connect.

So I have read and come up with solution like SQL Service  broker and SqlDependency with C# application.

So my questions are: can I rely on **SQL Service broker or SqlDependency** to achieve this? Because I do not want to lost/drop my any data as this are very important data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "too much database memory though sometime my db hangs when there are concurrent user try to connect." This sounds more like a problem with how you're interacting with the database, honestly. Include more details as to how the app connects (pools?), the DDL for any tables involved, queries involved, indexes, execution plans, version of MSSQL, and the SP and triggers you've tried.

Comment: Hi deepak. I don't think that `SqlDependency` (i.e. Query Notifications) is what you are looking for. Please review the "[Planning for Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187528(v=sql.105))" documentation. The top section states: "_Query notifications are useful in situations where an application reads data from the database frequently, but where updates to the data are relatively infrequent._". Then read the "**Alternatives to Query Notifications**" section.